# How to make id appear when deleting after radio button duplication

Tags: jquery, radio-button

```
$("#add").click(function()
    {
        var clone = $(".temp").clone(true);
        clone.find("input").prop("name", "employeeList[" + cloneId + "].type);
        cloneId++;
        clone.appendTo(".row");
    });

$("#delete").click(function() {...});
```

List after clicking Add button and Delete button

```
employeeList[0].type
employeeList[2].type
employeeList[4].type
```

How do I change it as follows?

```
employeeList[0].type
employeeList[1].type
employeeList[2].type
```